# MongoDB : Understanding MongoDB Internal Details .

Tags: mongodb

We are using Mongo DB for our Application .

Currently when i issue the `db.isMaster()` command in our Mongo Shell .

It displayed this below information ( This set up is currently associated with our development box )

```
PRIMARY> db.isMaster()
{
        "setName" : "dev",
        "ismaster" : true,
        "secondary" : false,
        "hosts" : [
                "10.11.13.111:27017",
                "10.11.13.111:27018"
        ],
        "arbiters" : [
                "10.11.13.111:27019"
        ],
        "primary" : "10.11.13.111:27017",
        "me" : "10.11.13.111:27017",
        "maxBsonObjectSize" : 16777216,
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Please let me know what does the above information means ??

1 . Does it mean that it  has got 1 primary and two secondary slaves ??  (One arbitrary also present in list )

1. How can i know if slaveOk is set to true or false ??

Thnaks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `setName` is the name of your replica set.
- `ismaster` obviously indicates whether the node you are connected to master or slave.
- `secondary` is contrary to `ismaster`.
- `hosts` are `host:port` pairs of nodes storing data in replica set.
- `arbiters` are `host:port` pairs of [arbiters](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/replica-sets/#replica-set-arbiters). These nodes can not store data, but their votes are used in master election process.
- `primary` indicates who is primary.
- `me` - indicates the node you are connected to.
- `maxBsonObjectSize` - 16MB for now. Just a very global constant.
- `ok` - kinda of a return code.

All can be found [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/isMaster/#isMaster). And regarding your questions:

1. No, you have two nodes. One primary (`10.11.13.111:27017`) and one slave (`10.11.13.111:27018`)
2. Check [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.readPref/#cursor.readPref). It is cursor operation.

Comment: Thank you very much , How can i know if slaveOk is set to true or false ??

Comment: a much easier way to know `slaveOk()` or not, make sure u r connecting to a secondary, query some data. if not `slaveOk()`, an error rises.

Comment: Even though i gave slaveok in Java Application its throwing an Application , saying couldn't connect to  master .

Comment: @PreethiJain update your question with log, maybe, or better create a new one.